# issue when running an exe file using PSexec

Tags: windows, remote-control, remote-connection, psexec

I'm having an error I'm not sure how to solve when trying to run an .exe file in a remote system:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PSTools>PsExec.exe \\172.19.15.50 -u doctor -p doctor "C:\Program Files\AppG\App.exe"

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of 
each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress 
socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
at AppG.CLI.TelnetServer.ListenForClients()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
C:\Program Files\AppG\App.exe exited on 172.19.15.50 with error 
code -532459699.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PSTools>
```

Another error I get is:

```
Found 1 matching device [ Vendor ID 0x10EE, Device ID 0x7 ]:

1. Vendor ID: 0x10EE, Device ID: 0x7


WARNING!!!
----------
Your hardware has level sensitive interrupts.

Interrupts
-----------

Found 1 matching device [ Vendor ID 0x10EE, Device ID 0x7 ]:

1. Vendor ID: 0x10EE, Device ID: 0x7
```

Anyone knows how to solve this, please?

Comment: Have you executed psexec to the same computer previously within a few minutes?

Comment: That error is from `C:\Program Files\AppG\App.exe` not `psexec`. Not something we can really help with without knowing what `app.exe` is.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure what you mean. I added another error I get.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's an app to manage this device: [link] (https://www.gpondoctor.com/gpondoctor4000/#1464945899060-e73e06de-4d14). So the device has a Windows 7 and I'd like to restart the app remotely.

Comment: I mean that this kind of error may come because an application has terminated and has closed its connected port, but the other side hasn't closed its port, so you need to wait a few minutes for everything to be closed correctly. The wait period can be shortened if required. So the question is: Does this happen on the first connect of the day when all devices are freshly booted? Or does this happen only on a subsequent connection?

Comment: @harrymc I think you are right, but I'm not sured how to solve it. I close the application, I did **taskkill /im App.exe /t /f** in the remote PC, it shown that it was terminated, I did **PsExec.exe \\172.19.15.50 -u doctor -p doctor "C:\Program Files\AppG\App.exe"** in the local PC, I got the second error I posted, and did **taskkill /im App.exe /t /f** in the remote PC and it closed a proccess!! However, the app GUI wasn't open...I know that you can access the app through Telnet using port 3000, but you can't restart it using this Telnet, only send commands to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that a bound port is not released.

I can see two possibilities:

- The program `App.exe` is stuck on termination and blocks any new invocation
  of itself.
  The only solution is to kill it using `taskkill`, wait a few minutes,
  and start again. The wait period could perhaps be shortened as described below.
- Windows is keeping a bound socket alive so as to let the other side complete
  any sending that it does. This is because TCP has no mechanism for notifying
  the device on the other side of the connection that the connection was
  terminated.

  The solution is to set in the registry at key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
  the DWORD entry `TcpTimedWaitDelay` to the number of seconds that
  Windows will wait before allowing another process to bind itself to the
  same TCP port.
  The default setting is 120, meaning 2 minutes, and you may set it as low as you
  like (zero is not recommended).
  This setting affects Windows only and not the other device.

  For more information see
  [Settings that can be Modified to Improve Network Performance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance).

Comment: thanks a lot! but in my **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters** there is no **TcpTimedWaitDelay**. Should I add it? Also, I kill the process, wait for more than 2 minutes and send the PSExec command but same thing as I mentioned: process is created but app is not opened.

Comment: You can create it if non-existent. This has no effect on the other device, so you may reduce the time to, say, 10 seconds, but will have to find out by waiting how much time is needed to fully liberate the connection on both sides.

Comment: I've created it, restarted the PC, wait, kill the process, run the PSExec commands and same 2nd error I posted. I've read here: [link](https://www.opswat.com/blog/powershell-vs-psexec-remote-command-execution) that Power Shell has some limitations so I wonder if PSExec has them too?

Comment: Is this the PC where you are running `App.exe`?

Comment: yes. The remote PC is where I created the key, killed the process, restarted, wait, restart and repeat...and wait for the PSExec commands to work (these are sent from the local PC). I've got remote desktop access to the remote PC but I need automate some tasks which involve running the App.exe remotely, using commands.

Comment: I don't know enough about the application, but it seems that you should avoid restarting it, if you can still communicate with it while it's running. It seems highly resistant to restarts.

Comment: I know...the problem is the application causes memory issues when it's running for a while, so restarting it is a solution but it seems it's impossible lol thanks anyway for the advice, it was very helpful maybe to use in the future with an less complicated application :)

Comment: You might instead of restarting the app to reboot the computer, which is also possible in remote.

Comment: yes, that works but we were looking for something faster

Comment: A wild idea for a way to eradicate the process and all it does is maybe to start it inside a [sandbox](https://www.sandboxie.com/), so that emptying the sandbox will undo everything. You should relax the restrictions on the sandbox enough to allow the program to function.

Comment: I didn't know about Sandbox. I understood that, if I add the App.exe in the Sandboxie Control panel, I can then run the initial PSExec command and it will launch the App.exe sandboxed? or maybe I have to change the path to the App.exe or add it in the Sandboxie Control panel with a different name?

Comment: This can be specified in sandbox *Properties > Program Start > Forced Folders*.

Comment: and then, I just run the PSExec command normally? However, now I'm not sure if this will work, because I've tried the same process but trying to open IE Explorer and I got this error after issuing the PSExec command:  **C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe exited on 172.19.15.50 with error code 1.** This remote system is a Windows Embedded so it may have some "special" configuration. For example, I enable Telnet, but then I'm not able to connect through port 23... coz I was thinking to try that instead of PSExec, but Telnet only works in the port enabled for the App.exe

Comment: The sandbox should be done on the App side. Sandboxie can also be used from the [command line](https://www.sandboxie.com/StartCommandLine).

Comment: if I do: **"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" "C:\Program Files\App.exe"** locally, it works. However, if I do: **PsExec.exe \\172.19.15.50 -u doctor -p doctor "C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" "C:\Program Files\App.exe"** I get this error: **C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe exited on 172.19.15.50 with error code -1073741502.** I've also tried **PsExec.exe \\172.19.15.50 -u doctor -p doctor "C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" default_browser** and got the same exactly error, when locally it does work.

Comment: just found something quite interesting: when running the original PSExec command, in the remote PC, PID is created for App.exe that I can see it from the command line, by using a script, but not in the task manager. However, in the task manager, a saw the process App.exe and PSEXESVC.exe (which is listed as a service too). However, App.exe user's is doctor and PSEXESVC.exe is SYSTEM...can this be messing around the full process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90620/discussion-between-natiya-and-harrymc).

Comment: Not having your environment, I'm getting to the limits of my ability to help here. The user accounts that you see are normal. You will have to experiment and see. It might be anything from conflict with the antivirus to needing admin permission or else.

Comment: I just marked your response as the correct answer because I've realized, although I can't see the App.exe opened in the remote system, it's running and work!! Coz I can send it commands through its own Telnet session and it works!! the issue was I couldn't see it before! :D